# Makefile: PHONY pattern match rule

Tags: makefile

I have an odd project were a few files are generated at build time. they are among other files but have a special sulffix. (as opposed to a normal project, where *all* files of some type means they were auto generated)

for example:

```
src/fileA.js
src/fileB.js.tpl
src/fileC.css
src/fileD.css.tpl
...
```

then i have a pattern rule:

```
DATA=$(get string from template.txt)
%: %.tpl
    sed 's/__TEMPLATE__/$(DATA)/g' $< > $@
templates: src/fileB.js src/fileD.css
```

And all is fine. Until the next build... now `src/fileB.js` will not get updated because there is one there already, and `src/fileB.js.tpl` was not changed, though the other file `template.txt` that i use as a data source to update it might. Which brings me to the clean step.

right now my clean step is `rm`ing each file. it is ugly.

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm src/fileB.js
    rm src/fileD.css
    ...
```

You can see how it gets ugly.

In a regular project my clean would be just `rm *.o` but here i can't do `rm *.js` as half the files are not auto-generated.

**is there any way to make the rule `%: %.tpl` be a PHONY?**

if not, is there any way to feed the file list from `template` into `clean`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
TEMPLATES=$(wildcard src/*.tpl)
GENERATED=$(TEMPLATES:%.tpl=%)

clean:
    rm -f $(GENERATED)
```

Well, I would backup before testing this...

Comment: nice! now my `templates` rule is also cleaner with `templates: $(GENERATED)`.  thanks a lot! always forget about `wildcard`

Comment: Manual required `clean` steps are a "code smell" for make. You shouldn't need to have them. The solution to the problem here is to use intermediate files that *always* get generated and then only update the actual `.js` file when it differs from the intermediate file. Yes, that is a bit costlier but means you can't forget to clean and end up with something broken.

Comment: "I would backup..." Or one can replace `rm` with `echo rm`.